# Create custom JSONresponse in spring web app

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm new with spring boot and i don't know how to handle the JSON response. Hope you can help me.

Here is my model

```
 @Entity
public class Employee {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String name, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
}
```

My Repository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

My controller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("employees/{id}")
    Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
}
```

My JSON file response

```
{"id":1,"name":"Bilbo Baggins","role":"burglar"},
```

I want some thing like

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Bilbo Baggins",
 "role": "burglar",
 "_links": {
   "self": {
     "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
   },
   "employees": {
     "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees"
   }
 }
}
```

By adding more detail to the JSON file. I followed the guide on spring.io with Hateoas but it didn't work. I think there may be another way to do this.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add HATEOAS dependency. In maven that would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>0.19.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I add it but the linkTo and methodOn doesn't work like the guide.  linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(employee.getId())).withSelfRel(),
you can see full guide here http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/